# How to change a string captured using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I am currently working on a text and I am struggling to do edit what have been captured using RegEx.

My text is split into sentences and there is one line per sentence. On each line, I locate using RegEx; emails, URLs, dates, etc. I would like the spaces found in what has been recognized by the different regexes to be replaced with "~".

Here is how I proceed to capture using regexes in the first place:

```
url = re.compile(ur"((\s|\A)((ht|f)tp(s)?://)?(www\.)?([\w\-\.]+)\.\w+([\w\-\./\?#]+)?\b)", re.I)
if url.search(line):
        line = url.sub(ur"{\1}__URL", line)
```

For now, I could not find a way to replace the spaces with "~" in what has been captured by the regexes. I tried things such as replace, a concatenation of re.subs, etc.

PS: There might be several things to be recognized within one sentence.

Comment: What's wrong with `str.replace()` method?

Comment: Perhaps, `print(re.sub(url, lambda x: x.group(0).replace(" ","~"), line))`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/oDlsM6).

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Kasramvd, I don't see how to properly apply str.replace on \1.

Comment: stribizhev, tis is very close to what I want. But the example I gave wasn't good.

If we try with :

`heure = re.compile(ur"(((0?\d)|(1\d)|(2[0-3]))( )?(:|heure(s)?|h)( )?((0\d)|([1-5]\d))?)", re.I)
if heure.search(line):
 line = heure.sub(ur"{\1}__HEURE", line)
line = "13 heures 30 23:56 15 h 12`

Would your code work to change the line variable to `line = "13~heures~30 23:56 15~h~12`?